# Disable iPhone timed auto lock when an app is running?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to disable the timed auto lock on an iPhone when a particular app is running?

I use my iPhone as a GPS and I have a dock that attaches it to my bike. When im using the GPS app id like the timed auto lock to be disabled.

Comment: Not sure if it is iPhone specific, but the App itself (assuming it is coded properly) can request the iPhone to not turn off the screen. One example is Google Map for iPad (don't have iPhone to test) - When "turn by turn navigation" is being used, it does not auto-lock. But if you only use it as a normal map, and not doing turn by turn navigation, it will auto-lock as per normal.

Comment: Sadly this app (Citymapper) doesnt have this feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to disable Auto-Lock for specific apps through iOS settings. A workaround is to manually disable Auto-Lock in settings, run the app, and then enable it again once you're done.

An app can request iOS to disable Auto-Lock. In this case, you should [contact the Citymapper developer](http://citymapper.com/contact/) for an update to allow this.

Answer (score 3):

Engage Google Maps turn-by-turn directions. Turn on your app with directions running in the background. Phone will stay on and lit indefinitely.  Close both apps when done.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working now, at least in iOS 13... i.e. I have Google Maps running and screen stays on. Take a call via bluetooth and phone switches to phone app and screen goes off. Hang up call and phone switches back to maps and screen comes back on