# How to disable screen time out for a specific iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

Is it possible to stop an iPad from going to sleep only when a specific app is open, even if nothing is being clicked/played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible with iOS settings.  You will have to goto settings and turn off auto-lock whenever you don't want the screen to turn off.

See here: [Disable iPhone timed auto lock when an app is running?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105927/disable-iphone-timed-auto-lock-when-an-app-is-running)

Answer (score 1):

Only the app itself can set that parameter. I have no clue how it is achieved, programatically, but some apps, such as SatNavs will never allow the device to sleep.

Try contacting the app makers to see if they might incorporate the setting in a future release.